# Spring Integration Default Message Listener Container IsRunning false

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a JMS Message Listener defined in Java DSL using the below configuration. The listener works fine. It processes the messages from queue as expected. I had not configured autostartup as the default value is true and I need the listener to be running once the application starts. When i try to invoke  the  isRunning() method during application startup, isRunning method returns false. Is there some configuration that I am missing here

```
/**
Configuration for  the Message Listener
**/
@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer inListener(){
DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
defaultMessageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory((ConnectionFactory)connectionFactory().getObject());
defaultMessageListenerContainer.setDestinationName(queueName);
defaultMessageListenerContainer.setIdleTaskExecutionLimit(100);
defaultMessageListenerContainer.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(1);
defaultMessageListenerContainer.setSessionTransacted(true);
defaultMessageListenerContainer.setPubSubDomain(false);
defaultMessageListenerContainer.setDestinationResolver(jndiDestResolver);
}

@Bean
public JndiObjectFactoryBean connectionFactory(){
JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate);
jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName(jndiName);
return jndiObjectFactoryBean;
}
```

Message Listener

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow adapter(){
return IntegrationFlow.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(inListener()).channel(inputChannel()).get();
}
```

Code for IsRunning: This code  is being used in the postconstruct method of another class. The first print statement for Autostartup is printing true while the isRunning print statement is printing false. Is there some configuration  that is missing here

```
AbstractMessageListenerContainer listener = (AbstractMessageListenerContainer) applicationContext.getBean("inListener");
System.out.println("Autostartup: "+ listener.isAutoStartup());
System.out.println("Running: "+ listener.isRunning());
```

Comment: Not clear how you use that `inListener`. Not clean what `isRunning()` you call and where. What is really a problem? What made you to come here with such a question? Maybe you try to check that status too early? Are you sure that your problem is relevant somehow to Spring Integration: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration ?

Comment: ArtemBilan Added the code details for InListener and invoking the isRunning method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@PostConstruct` is too early for lifecycle control. This one is fully an equivalent to the `afterPropertiesSet()` for particular bean. The `start()` for autoStartup lifecylces is called a bit later when all the beans in the application context is ready already.

For your logic you should consider really to implement a `SmartLifecycle` to perform a desired logic.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-processor